# How can I overwrite data in csv file using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am using Jmeter for API automation, I am writing result pass or fail in CSV file.

I am unable to overwrite old result data, Every time I run the test cases it's appending with old result data.

I use Beanshell Post processor for writing in CSV file.

```
import java.io.file;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

ActualResponseCode = prev.getResponseCode();


if (vars.get("ExpectedResponse").equals(vars.get("ActualResponse"))) 

{
if(vars.get("ExpectedResponseCode").equals(prev.getResponseCode()))
    {
        prev.setSuccessful(true);
        Result = "Pass";
         ErrorMessage = "No Error"; 
    }           
    else
    {
        Result = "Fail";
        ErrorMessage = "ResponseCode not matching";

    }

}   
else 
{
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    Result = "Fail";
    ErrorMessage = "ResponseData is not matching";
}


f = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//a622821//Desktop//apache-jmeter-3.2//API_AUTOMATION//TestResult_Post.csv", true);

p = new PrintStream(f);
p.println(vars.get("TestCase") + "," + vars.get("API_Endpoint") + "," + vars.get("ExpectedResponseCode") + "," + ActualResponseCode + "," + Result + "," + ErrorMessage);

p.close();
f.close();
```

Comment: Can you add your code of file creation (beanshell)

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you write to file you can overrid file by using boolean `false` as second parameter to FileWriter constructor

```
File file = ....

new FileWriter(file, false);
```

If you have several calls for beanshell I suggest create Beanshell sampler which will be called in start of the test and will override the file (create empty file):

```
import java.io.file;
f = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//a622821//Desktop//apache-jmeter-3.2//API_AUTOMATION//TestResult_Post.csv", false);

p = new PrintStream(f);    

p.close();
f.close();
```

If you **must** use same beanshell you need a variable flag, so add variable firstTime with value true

In Beanshell use it to set the flag by firstTime variable:

```
import java.io.file;
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

ActualResponseCode = prev.getResponseCode();


if (vars.get("ExpectedResponse").equals(vars.get("ActualResponse"))) 

{
if(vars.get("ExpectedResponseCode").equals(prev.getResponseCode()))
    {
        prev.setSuccessful(true);
        Result = "Pass";
         ErrorMessage = "No Error"; 
    }           
    else
    {
        Result = "Fail";
        ErrorMessage = "ResponseCode not matching";

    }

}   
else 
{
    prev.setSuccessful(false);
    Result = "Fail";
    ErrorMessage = "ResponseData is not matching";
}

firstTime = vars.get("firstTime");

flag = true;
if ("true".equals(firstTime)) {
  flag = false;
  vars.put("firstTime", "false");
}
f = new FileOutputStream("C://Users//a622821//Desktop//apache-jmeter-3.2//API_AUTOMATION//TestResult_Post.csv", flag);


p = new PrintStream(f);
p.println(vars.get("TestCase") + "," + vars.get("API_Endpoint") + "," + vars.get("ExpectedResponseCode") + "," + ActualResponseCode + "," + Result + "," + ErrorMessage);

p.close();
f.close();
```

Test Plan variable:
[image: variable]

Comment: I have tried using new FileWriter(file, false); but its overriding only last result. I have 8 testcases and its overriding only my last testcase. other testcase results are not showing in file.

Comment: I have added my code in my question, I have used only one file for writing all testcases result

Comment: can u please share more details how can i use beanshell sampler for several calls

Comment: Yes I have added variable firstTime with value true, but nothing is writing in my csv file

Comment: I added your code to my solution. it worked in my computer. I added variable in Test Plan component

Comment: I did the same, I have also added variable in Test Plan. can u please show once how u have defined vaiable

Answer (score 0):

Don't use scripting to write anything to files, JMeter is able to store literally anything into its .jtl results file so I would recommend rather configuring it to store what you need there rather than trying to create an extra results file in such a weird manner as:

- Beanshell is not the best scripting option, if you need to go for scripting consider using [JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language instead](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)
- If you are writing something into a file make sure you put aforementioned JSR223 Elements under the [Critical Section Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Critical_Section_Controller)

---

So I would suggest switching to either [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) or [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) instead of the PostProcessor. If required you can tell JMeter to store assertion failure message by adding the next line to *user.properties* file (located in the "bin" folder of JMeter installation, however I think it defaults to `true` in any case)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
```

Check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) for more details.